# Como puedo hacer un validador para cada campo de un formulario

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Estoy haciendo un formulario donde no deberias poder escribir hasta que el campo anterior no este rellenado y asi hasta el final, tengo como unos 9 campos. Como puedo hacer ese validador?

Comment: Con javascript, desactivas todos lo demás campos excepto el primero y mediante programación en el método change del campo validas si lo escrito es valido y activas el proximo campo

Comment: Igual esta no es una funcionalidad comun.. que pasa si relleno unos campos y despues voy y borro los de arriba? que pasa con los de abajo? los vas a blanquear? que pasa si solo lo borre para cambiarlo?